# Start Activity from GridView

Tags: android, gridview

I create a GridView and I want to start some activities from each button.
The gridView is in a class called Status, the code as follows:

```
public class Status extends AppCompatActivity {

    Toolbar toolbar;
    CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayoutAndroid;
    CoordinatorLayout rootLayoutAndroid;
    GridView gridView;

    public static String[] gridViewStrings = {
            "Stato",
            "Allarmi",
            "Impostazioni",
            "Numero SIM",
            "Dati Impianto",
            "Esci",

    };
    public static int[] gridViewImages = {
            R.drawable.chart,
            R.drawable.alert,
            R.drawable.set,
            R.drawable.sim_status,
            R.drawable.impianto2,
            R.drawable.close,
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.status);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid);
        gridView.setAdapter(new CustomAndroidGridViewAdapter(this, gridViewStrings, gridViewImages));

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Status.class);
                        i.putExtra("id", position);
                        startActivity(i);
                        break;

                    case 1:
                        finish();
                        break;
                }

            }
        });

        initInstances();


    }

    private void initInstances() {
        rootLayoutAndroid = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.android_coordinator_layout);
        collapsingToolbarLayoutAndroid = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar_android_layout);
        collapsingToolbarLayoutAndroid.setTitle("ESA MOBILE App");
    }
}
```

And my Adapter class as follows : I want to start activity from first button and to close the activity from second one, but doesn't work.

```
class CustomAndroidGridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private final String[] string;
    private final int[] Imageid;

    CustomAndroidGridViewAdapter(Context c,String[] string,int[] Imageid ) {
        mContext = c;
        this.Imageid = Imageid;
        this.string = string;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return string.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int p) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int p) {
        return 0;
    }

    @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
    @Override
    public View getView(int p, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View grid;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (convertView == null) {

            grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_custom_layout, null);
            TextView textView = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.gridview_text);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView)grid.findViewById(R.id.gridview_image);
            textView.setText(string[p]);
            imageView.setImageResource(Imageid[p]);
        } else {
            grid = convertView;
        }



        return grid;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should update your getView() to set the correct click listener. It also seems you have a bug when you recycle views as you don't update them in the adapter (BTW, using a the View Holder pattern would make this code more efficient):

```
@SuppressLint("InflateParams")
@Override
public View getView(int p, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View grid;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if (convertView == null) {
        grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_custom_layout, null);
    } else {
        grid = convertView;
    }

    TextView textView = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.gridview_text);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView)grid.findViewById(R.id.gridview_image);
    textView.setText(string[p]);
    imageView.setImageResource(Imageid[p]);

    // Here you can set your click listener.
    // Another option is to have a OnClickListener array (like you have for the strings and images and use it in a similar way). 
    grid.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (p) {
                case 0:
                    // Start activity
                    break;
                case 1:
                    // Close
                    break;
                default:
                    // Do something else
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
    return grid;
}
```

Comment: With this code the activity starts when click on the blank space around the image. But doesn't work clicking on the image.

Comment: I solved my problem using imageView.setOnClickListener instead of grid.setOnClickListener.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but i think you are requesting click on the item(not on the ImageView inside the item)

so implement click in adapter after get the id of your parent or you can implement the click on your image in adapter like:

```
 imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

//Toast here

    }});
```

Comment: I need to start different activities from each image or from each item (is the same)

Comment: this method will implement in  getView(int p, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)  method where you will get the position (p). so you can implement switch cases in onClick method like you implemented in Activity

Comment: Or please check in your item XML .TextView or ImageView should not be clickable or clickable properties not be set(If you want to implement click in Activity not in adapter). you can use android:focusable="false" android:focusableInTouchMode="false" both properties in every item in item XML then no problem will be occur to click on GridView in activity